# Save LinearLayout with multiple TextView. Android

Tags: java, android, textview, save, android-linearlayout

I have method. They add a new number (with different colors and gravity), each time you press the button. After some clicks i have LinearLayout with multiple TextView. And i dont understand, how to save it. After closing the application, it opens with a blank layout. But i need to save previous TextView's.

```
public void someText(String message) {

TextView message = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
message.setText(message);
message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textsmallest);
message.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
message.setGravity(Gravity.START);
messageLayout.addView(message);
```

(I am really sorry, english is not my native language.)

Comment: You need to save the message in SharedPreference and populate TextView when the activity is created again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences save message or other value to xml.
Link this:

```
    Context ctx = MainActivity.this;       
    SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences("SP", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("STRING_KEY", "string");
    editor.putInt("INT_KEY", 0);
    editor.putBoolean("BOOLEAN_KEY", true);
    editor.commit();
```